# Display end_of_year balance of a company by year and period

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a financial Redshift table which displays the values (**period_value**) for each period in a given year, and a running total (**period_balance**) based on the company_id, account_no & period_no.

I need to display the period_balance last period in a given year to display the **end_balance**.

example (expected result):

| company_id | account_no | year_no | period_no | period_value | period_balance | end_balance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2020 | 1 | 100 | 100 | 1000 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2020 | 2 | 200 | 300 | 1000 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2020 | 3 | 300 | 600 | 1000 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2020 | 4 | 400 | 1000 | 1000 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2021 | 1 | 50 | 1050 | 1350 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2021 | 2 | 75 | 1125 | 1350 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2021 | 3 | 125 | 1250 | 1350 |
| 1002 | 10003 | 2021 | 4 | 100 | 1350 | 1350 |
| 1111 | 12222 | 2020 | 1 | 200 | 200 | 400 |
| 1111 | 12222 | 2020 | 2 | 200 | 400 | 400 |
| -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |

I've tried the following query which generates an **end_balance**, but the preceding year total is not correct.

```
with transactions as (
select
    company_id,
    company_name,
    year_no,
    account_no,
    period_no,
    period_value,
    sum(period_value) over (partition by company_id, account_no order by year_no, period_no rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as period_balance,
    SUM(period_value) over (partition by company_id, account_no, year_no - 1) as end_balance
from schema.table_name
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
),

final as (
select
    company_id,
    company_name,
    year_no,
    account_no,
    period_no,
    period_value,
    period_balance,
    end_balance
from transactions
)

select *
from final
```

Answer (score 0):

You must modify your query in order to calculate each year's end_balance correctly. Instead of calculating the end_balance across all years, you should do so independently for each year. To do this, I modified your query as follows:

```
WITH transactions AS (
    SELECT
        company_id,
        account_no,
        year_no,
        period_no,
        period_value,
        SUM(period_value) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id, account_no, year_no ORDER BY year_no, period_no) AS period_balance
    FROM schema.table_name
),
end_balances AS (
    SELECT
        company_id,
        account_no,
        year_no,
        MAX(period_no) AS last_period_no,
        SUM(period_value) AS end_balance
    FROM transactions
    GROUP BY company_id, account_no, year_no
)
SELECT
    t.company_id,
    t.account_no,
    t.year_no,
    t.period_no,
    t.period_value,
    t.period_balance,
    eb.end_balance
FROM transactions t
JOIN end_balances eb
ON t.company_id = eb.company_id
    AND t.account_no = eb.account_no
    AND t.year_no = eb.year_no
    AND t.period_no = eb.last_period_no
ORDER BY t.company_id, t.account_no, t.year_no, t.period_no;
```

Hope it works :)